# how to skip null values ​by retrieving data with session.get in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, get, nullpointerexception

I would like to retrieve some data from the database, but there are two errors, NullPointerException and "Unable to locater persister". There are null values ​​in my database, how can they be skipped? Shouldn't it retrieve the tuple with that specific primary key I provided in session.get? Then the tuple exists in my database, so why does it tell me it's not persistent? Thank you.

```
Parliamentary class

@Entity
@Table(name = "parlamentari")
@IdClass(Parlamentare.class)
public class Parlamentare implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "nome")
 String nome;
@Id
@Column(name = "partito")
 String partito;
@Id
@Column(name = "circoscrizione")
 String circoscrizione;
 Date data_nascita; 
 String luogo; 
 String titolo_studi; 
 String[] mandati; 
 String[] commissioni;
 //DateRange[] periodo_carica;
 
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parlamentare",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Range2<LocalDate>> periodo_carica = new ArrayList<Range2<LocalDate>>();
 
 public Parlamentare() {
    
        this.nome = "";
        this.partito = "";
        this.circoscrizione = "";  
        this.data_nascita = null;
        this.luogo = null;
        this.titolo_studi = "";
        this.mandati = null;
        this.commissioni = null; 
        this.periodo_carica = null;
 }
 
public Parlamentare(String nome, String partito, String circoscrizione) {
    super();
    this.nome = nome;
    this.partito = partito;
    this.circoscrizione = circoscrizione;
}



public Parlamentare(String nome, String partito, String circoscrizione, Date data_nascita, String luogo,
        String titolo_studi, String[] mandati, String[] commissioni, List<Range2<LocalDate>> periodo_carica) {
    super();
    this.nome = nome;
    this.partito = partito;
    this.circoscrizione = circoscrizione;
    this.data_nascita = data_nascita;
    this.luogo = luogo;
    this.titolo_studi = titolo_studi;
    this.mandati = mandati;
    this.commissioni = commissioni;
    this.periodo_carica = periodo_carica;
}

....

}       
}
```

The Range2 class is the same as Vlad Mihalcea's Range class with the addition of:

```
@ManyToMany
private Parlamentare parlamentare;


public Parlamentare getParlamentare() {
    return parlamentare;
}


public void setParlamentare(Parlamentare parlamentare) {
    this.parlamentare = parlamentare;
}
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Parlamento</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

App.java

```
public class App 
{
private static ServiceRegistry serviceregistry;
private static SessionFactory sf;
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sf == null) {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new 
 StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        sf = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }
    return sf;
}

public static void main( String[] args )throws ParseException, NullPointerException{

Parlamentare parlamentare = new Parlamentare();

Configuration con  = new 
Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Parlamentare.class).addAnnotatedClass(Range2.class);      
    
     //serviceregistry.applySettings(con.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    getSessionFactory();

    serviceregistry = new 
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(con.getProperties()).build();
    try {
 sf = con.buildSessionFactory(serviceregistry);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction(); 

    parlamentare = (Parlamentare) session.get(Parlamentare.class, 
            new Parlamentare("Abate Rosa Silvana","M5S", "Calabria"));
    //parlamentare.getpk("Abate Rosa Silvana","M5S", "Calabria"));

    System.out.println(parlamentare.getNome());
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getPartito());
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getCircoscrizione());
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getData_nascita());
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getLuogo());
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getTitolo_studi());
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getMandati()); 
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getCommissioni()); 
    System.out.println(parlamentare.getPeriodo_carica());

    
    List<Range2<LocalDate>> periodo_carica = new ArrayList<Range2<LocalDate>>();
    periodo_carica = parlamentare.getPeriodo_carica();
    for(Range2<LocalDate> dr : periodo_carica)
    {
        System.out.println(dr);
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
   // tx.commit();
    session.close();
    sf.close();
}
```

}

```
     OUTPUT:

mag 01, 2021 10:49:19 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
     mag 01, 2021 10:49:19 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager

 <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
mag 01, 2021 10:49:20 AM 
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
 WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
 mag 01, 2021 10:49:20 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL 
[jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Parlamento]
mag 01, 2021 10:49:20 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres}
mag 01, 2021 10:49:20 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
mag 01, 2021 10:49:20 AM 
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections

<init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
mag 01, 2021 10:49:21 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
mag 01, 2021 10:49:24 AM 
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl

getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7 a18e8d] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will 
 be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
mag 01, 2021 10:49:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator

initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: 
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
 mag 01, 2021 10:49:25 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
mag 01, 2021 10:49:25 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL 
[jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Parlamento]
mag 01, 2021 10:49:25 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres}
 mag 01, 2021 10:49:25 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
mag 01, 2021 10:49:25 AM 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections

<init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
 mag 01, 2021 10:49:26 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
 INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
 java.lang.NullPointerException     at 
org.hibernate.cfg.ColumnsBuilder.extractMetadata(ColumnsBuilder.java:144)   at 
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1685)    at 
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2790)    at 
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:2893)  at 
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.mapAsIdClass(AnnotationBinder.java:1063)     at 
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:791)     at  
org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.
processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:248)    at  
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies
(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:239)  at 
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete
(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:282)  at 
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build
(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)    
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build 
(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)  at 
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build
(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)   at 
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory
(Configuration.java:689)    at 
swt.mvn.Parlamento.App.main(App.java:132)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException:
Unable to locate persister: 
swt.mvn.Parlamento.src.Servlet_Parlamento.Parlamentari.Parlamentare     at 
org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:721)    at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2946)     at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1800(SessionImpl.java:193)    at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2675)   at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2658)   at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1140)  at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:983)    at 
swt.mvn.Parlamento.App.main(App.java:139)
```

[image: Parlamentare.java]

[image: PK.java]

[image: Range2.java]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that don't seem right at first glance:

**1. many-to-many association**

You used a `@ManyToMany` on a single field:

```
@ManyToMany
private Parlamentare parlamentare;
```

This is not correct because you cannot have many `Parlamentare` if the association doesn't use a `Collection`. You need to change it to:

```
@ManyToMany
Set<Parlamentare> parlamentari;
```

or

```
@ManyToOne
Parlamentare parlamentare;
```

If it refers to a single parlamentare.

Check the Hibernate ORM documentation for examples of [`@ManyToMany` associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many) and [`@ManyToOne` associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one).

**2. @IdClass**

You can use [`@IdClass` to create composite identifiers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated), but you have to create a class that maps the identifier:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parlamentari")
@IdClass(ParlamentarePK.class)
public class Parlamentare implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "nome")
 String nome;

@Id
@Column(name = "partito")
 String partito;

@Id
@Column(name = "circoscrizione")
String circoscrizione;
 ...
}

public class ParlamentarePK implements Serializable {

    String nome;

    String partito;

    String circoscrizione;

   ...// getters,setters and so on
}
```

**3. EAGER associations**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy ="parlamentare",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Range2<LocalDate>> periodo_carica = new ArrayList<Range2<LocalDate>>();
```

This might be correct, but it's usually discouraged to map associations as eager. It may lead to poor performance because the association will always be loaded even when you don't need it.

You can eagerly fetch associations [via queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching) or [via an entity graph](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-entity-graph) only when you need them instead.

To make it lazy, you can change the mapping to:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy ="parlamentare",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Range2<LocalDate>> periodo_carica = new ArrayList<Range2<LocalDate>>();
```

**4. Arrays as type**

Example:

```
String[] commissioni;
```

Hibernate ORM will save this values as [an array of binary bytes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-array-binary).
I'm not sure if this is what you want.
[This article about mapping arrays](https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-arrays-with-hibernate/) explain all the options.

Comment: I made the necessary corrections but now it gives me another error: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: parlamentari, for columns:

Comment: I would need to see the mapping, but make sure that all the annotations are on fields and not on the getter/setter. If possible.

Comment: i added screenshots

Comment: The error happens becase `List<...> periodo_carica` is not annotated anymore. If it's an  association, you need to map it with `@OnetMany` or `@ManyToMany`. Check the HIbernate ORM documentation. It contains all the explanation you need: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many

Comment: StackOverflow is not the best place for this kind of open questions and you are not supposed to update the same question over and over. The Hibernate Forum (https://discourse.hibernate.org/c/hibernate-orm/5) or the Zulip chat (https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/login/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user) might work better for this. Good luck!

Comment: I annotated periodo_carica with @OneToMany, but the error remained the same

Comment: I might be able to help you if you publish some code on GitHub or somewhere I can have a look. Otherwise I would suggest to use the forum or zulip links I gave you before

Comment: If you give me your email, I'll send you the file.rar, on github it seems complicated to do a simple upload of a file

Comment: Mmmh...That's not how things get done usually. If you create an account on Zulip (https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user), you should be able to find me there easily. I don't feel comfortable sharing my email address here (although is not hard to find if you look at the Hibernate Reactive documentation).